# Clarifications for McEliece's algorithm for factoring polynomials over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

I'm trying to parse McEliece's paper on [Factorization of Polynomials over Finite Fields](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/91b8/d2172d6ceeb99fd548532483aa8f3a99c8e5.pdf), particularly the algorithm rather than the proof of why it works, and although I understand part of it, something escapes me.

On p. 865 the paper says that to factor the squarefree $\bar{f} = x^7+x^5+x^4+x+1$ (represented in binary as `10110011`) in $GF(2)[x]$, we compute $T_1(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} x^{2^k} \bmod \bar{f} = x^6 + x^2 + x + 1$ (`1000111`) and then because of Theorem 1, we can write $\bar{f}$ as

$$\bar{f}=\gcd(\bar{f},T_1(x)) \cdot \gcd(\bar{f},g(x))$$

where $g(x) = x^5 + x + 1$ (`100011`) just appears in the paper and I'm not sure where it comes from.

Where did this polynomial come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theorem 1 implies that 
$$\overline{f}=\prod_{a\in GF(2)}\gcd(\overline{f},T_1(x)-a).$$
With $a=0$ you get the factor $\gcd(\overline{f};T_1(x))$. The other factor is then surely $\gcd(\overline{f},T_1(x)-1)$. The polynomial $g(x)$ that you are asking about comes from the observation
$$
T_1(x)-1=x g(x).
$$
The trivial factor $x$ of $T_1(x)-1$ can be left out, because $x\nmid \overline{f}$.

Comment: This is just an educated guess.

Comment: Oh. ok, that makes sense.

Comment: Sometimes I wish that mathematicians could encode their papers in short form and long form, where the short form is for each other, and the long form is for the less mathematically-nimble of us and doesn't leave out the skipped steps.